NotifyItemRemoved() not working properly. Deleting wrong element
I have a list of 8 countries and i want that when the arrow image of the first country is clicked then the second country name (china) should be deleted from the list. but instead 3rd country gets deleted. My country adapter code is given below

After clicking on first country arrow the list become

Below is my Country Adapter code
class CountryAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val activity: Activity,
    private val countries: MutableList<Countries>,
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var isPressed = false
    private var deletedList: HashMap<Int, Countries> = HashMap()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val viewHolder: CountryViewHolder
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val holderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_item, parent, false)
        viewHolder = CountryViewHolder(holderView)
        viewHolder.countryName = holderView.findViewById(R.id.countryName)
        viewHolder.arrowImg = holderView.findViewById(R.id.arrow)
        return viewHolder
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
        val viewHolder = holder as CountryViewHolder
        val txt = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.countryName)
        val baseLayout = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.base_linear_layout)
        val basedecLayout = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.base_des_layout)
        val arrow = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.arrow)
        if (position != 0) {
            arrow.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            basedecLayout.setOnClickListener {
                arrow.performClick()
            }
            arrow.setOnClickListener {
                if (!isPressed) {
                    for (i in 1..1) {
                        deletedList[i] = countries[1]
                        countries.removeAt(1)   //Problem is here
                        notifyItemRemoved(1)    // problem is here
                    }
                }
//                else {
//                    for (i in 3 downTo 1) {
//                        countries.add(1, deletedList[i]!!)
//                        notifyItemInserted(1)
//                    }
//                    deletedList.clear()
//                }
                isPressed = !isPressed
            }
        }
        txt.text = countries[position].name
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return countries.size
    }

    class CountryViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        lateinit var countryName: TextView
        lateinit var arrowImg: ImageView
    }
}


The issue you're encountering stems from the logic used when clicking the arrow image.  The problem lies in the fact that you're always removing the country at index 1 (countries[1]) regardless of which arrow is clicked. This happens because the logic inside the arrow.setOnClickListener block doesn't take into account which arrow was clicked.
To fix this issue, you need to dynamically determine which country to remove based on the arrow that was clicked. Since you want to remove the country after the arrow that was clicked, you should use the position parameter passed to onBindViewHolder.
By using adapterPosition, you ensure that the logic correctly removes the country following the arrow that was clicked. Additionally, the if statement inside the setOnClickListener block checks if there's a valid country to remove after the clicked arrow.
arrow.setOnClickListener {
    val position = adapterPosition
    if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return@setOnClickListener //Safety check

    if (!isPressed) {
        // Check if the position is valid for removal
        if (position + 1 < countries.size) {
            deletedList[position + 1] = countries[position + 1]
            countries.removeAt(position + 1)
            notifyItemRemoved(position + 1)
        }
    }
    isPressed = !isPressed
}


Thanks for your reply...but yesterday i found the cause of the issue...the problem was in this line "holder.setIsRecyclable(false)"...when i removed it..it worked fine
